# How can I resize a part of the text in a node using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize

I have this graph where the times above the nodes is the departure time. How can I format the "+1" better? It stands for the "next day". Now is too big with respect to the time, and also the 'plus' is exaggerated. I was trying to put the "+1" smaller and maybe with a different colour.

How can I achieve this? Thanks!

**EDIT:** How can I also reduce the white part that covers each edges? (the part in the middle of the edge covered by a number)

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{color,xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree, tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.text,backgrounds}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={font issue=\footnotesize},
    font issue/.style={execute at begin picture={#1\selectfont}}
}

\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.17}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{clock}
\usepackage[clock]{ifsym}

\ClockFrametrue\ClockStyle=0

\newcommand{\orig}{\mathcal{O}} % origin position
\newcommand{\dest}{\mathcal{D}} % destination position

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,thick,draw}]
            \node[fill=red!30] (Orig) at (0,0) {$\orig$};
            \node (A) at (2,2) {A};
            \node (B) at (2.3,0.5) {B};
            \node (C) at (3.3,-1.2) {C};
            \node (H) at (4.2,2.1) {H};
            \node (L) at (6.4,-0.5) {L};
            \node (E) at (5.9,1.9) {E} ;
            \node[fill=green!30] (Dest) at (8,1) {$\dest$};
        \end{scope}
        
        \begin{scope}[>={stealth[black]},
            every node/.style={fill=white,circle},
            every edge/.style={draw=red,very thick}]
            \path [->] (Orig) edge node {$5$} (A);
            \path [->] (A) edge node {$5$} (H);
            \path [->] (H) edge node {$3$} (E);
            \path [->] (E) edge node {$8$} (Dest); 
            % \path [->] (B) edge[bend right=60] node {$1$} (E); 
        \end{scope}
    
        \begin{scope}[>={stealth[black]},
            every node/.style={fill=white,circle},
            every edge/.style={draw=black,very thick}]
            \path [->] (Orig) edge node {$5$} (B);
            \path [->] (Orig) edge node {$5$} (C);
            \path [->] (B) edge node {$3$} (C);
            \path [->] (B) edge node {$3$} (H);
            \path [->] (B) edge node {$3$} (L);
            \path [->] (C) edge node {$5$} (L);
            \path [->] (E) edge node {$8$} (L); 
            \path [->] (L) edge node {$8$} (Dest); 
        \end{scope}
    

        \begin{scope}[font=\tiny]
            \node [above=0.5pt of A] {\clock{15}{30} 15:30};
            \node [below=0.5pt of Orig] {\clock{18}{15} 18:15};
            \node [above=0.5pt of H] {\clock{8}{30} 8:30$^{+1}$};
            \node [above=0.5pt of E] {\clock{10}{45} 10:45$^{+1}$};
            \node [above=0.5pt of Dest, align=center] {Arrive \\ \clock{12}{00} 12:00$^{+1}$};
        \end{scope}

    
        \matrix [draw,above left, row sep=1mm, nodes={font=\scriptsize}] at (current bounding box.north east) {
            \node [circle, black, draw, label=right:Hotel] {H}; \\
            \node [circle, black, draw, label=right:Lunch] {L}; \\
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph]

Comment: For the edges, use `inner sep=1pt` (or any size that suits you). For the clocks, you could scale them using `scale=0.8` in the node definition, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would a bit redesign your image. I suggest to use :

- `quotes` library for edges labels
- at nodes O,A,H,E and D use `labels` for time information
- most of styles write as option to `tikzpicture`:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{clock}
\ClockFrametrue\ClockStyle=1

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
C/.style = {circle, draw, fill=#1, minimum size=1em, inner sep=1pt},
C/.default = white,
every label/.style = {align=center, font=\tiny, inner sep=2pt},
every edge/.style = {draw, - Stealth, thick},
every edge quotes/.style = {font=\scriptsize, text=black, fill=white, inner sep=2pt}
                        ]
\node (O) [C=red!30, 
           label=below:\clock{18}{15}\\\scriptsize{18:15}]  {$\mathcal{O}$};
\node (A) [C,
           label=above:\clock{15}{30}\\\scriptsize{15:30}]          at (2,2)    {A};
\node (B) [C] at (2.3,0.5) {B};
\node (C) [C] at (3.3,-1.2) {C};
\node (H) [C, 
           label=above:\clock{8}{30}\\\scriptsize{8:30$^{+1}$}]      at (4,2)    {H};
\node (L) [C] at (6.4,-0.5) {L};
\node (E) [C, 
           label=above:\clock{10}{45}\\\scriptsize{10:45$^{+1}$}]   at (6,2)    {E} ;
\node (D) [C=green!30,
           label=85:{\scriptsize Arrive:\\[1ex] 
                        \clock{12}{00}
                        \scriptsize 12:00$^{+1}$}]  at (8,1)    {$\mathcal{D}$};

\path [red] (O) edge ["5"]  (A) 
            (A) edge ["5"]  (H) 
            (H) edge ["3"]  (E) 
            (E) edge ["8"]  (D);
\path       (O) edge ["5"]  (B)
            (O) edge ["5"]  (C)
            (B) edge ["3"]  (C)
            (B) edge ["3"]  (H)
            (B) edge ["3"]  (L)
            (C) edge ["5"]  (L)
            (E) edge ["8"]  (L)
            (L) edge ["8"]  (D);

\matrix [draw,above left, row sep=1mm] 
        at (current bounding box.north east) 
{\node [C, label=right:Hotel] {H}; \\
 \node [C, label=right:Lunch] {L}; \\
};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nicer solution, indeed. Still, I don't understand why I don't get the clock to print, even with your code...

Comment: @SebGlav, I tested (and show result of compilation) with recent MiKTeX and used package versions (`article.cls    2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
   clock.sty    2001/04/10 v0.1 TeXclock
    tikz.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
     pgf.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)`.  I tested again and get the same result as shown in answer.

Comment: Considering the date of `clock.sty`, I shouldn't get this error, but I'll update my TeX distribution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why clocks don't come up for me, but the rest is ok, so...

[image: resize font in nodes]

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{color,xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree, tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.text,backgrounds}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={font issue=\footnotesize},
    font issue/.style={execute at begin picture={#1\selectfont}}
}

\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.17}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{clock}
\usepackage[clock]{ifsym}

\ClockFrametrue\ClockStyle=0

\newcommand{\orig}{\mathcal{O}} % origin position
\newcommand{\dest}{\mathcal{D}} % destination position

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,thick,draw}]
            \node[fill=red!30] (Orig) at (0,0) {$\orig$};
            \node (A) at (2,2) {A};
            \node (B) at (2.3,0.5) {B};
            \node (C) at (3.3,-1.2) {C};
            \node (H) at (4.2,2.1) {H};
            \node (L) at (6.4,-0.5) {L};
            \node (E) at (5.9,1.9) {E} ;
            \node[fill=green!30] (Dest) at (8,1) {$\dest$};
        \end{scope}
        
        \begin{scope}[>={stealth[black]},
            every node/.style={fill=white,circle, inner sep = 0.5pt},
            every edge/.style={draw=red,very thick}]
            \path [->] (Orig) edge node {$5$} (A);
            \path [->] (A) edge node {$5$} (H);
            \path [->] (H) edge node {$3$} (E);
            \path [->] (E) edge node {$8$} (Dest); 
            % \path [->] (B) edge[bend right=60] node {$1$} (E); 
        \end{scope}
    
        \begin{scope}[>={stealth[black]},
            every node/.style={fill=white,circle,inner sep=0.5pt},
            every edge/.style={draw=black,very thick}]
            \path [->] (Orig) edge node {$5$} (B);
            \path [->] (Orig) edge node {$5$} (C);
            \path [->] (B) edge node {$3$} (C);
            \path [->] (B) edge node {$3$} (H);
            \path [->] (B) edge node {$3$} (L);
            \path [->] (C) edge node {$5$} (L);
            \path [->] (E) edge node {$8$} (L); 
            \path [->] (L) edge node {$8$} (Dest); 
        \end{scope}
    

        \begin{scope}[font=\tiny, every node/.style={scale=0.8}]
            \node [above=0.5pt of A] {\clock{15}{30} 15:30};
            \node [below=0.5pt of Orig] {\clock{18}{15} 18:15};
            \node [above=0.5pt of H] {\clock{8}{30} 8:30$^{+1}$};
            \node [above=0.5pt of E] {\clock{10}{45} 10:45$^{+1}$};
            \node [above=0.5pt of Dest, align=center] {Arrive \\ \clock{12}{00} 12:00$^{+1}$};
        \end{scope}

    
        \matrix [draw,above left, row sep=1mm, nodes={font=\scriptsize}] at (current bounding box.north east) {
            \node [circle, black, draw, label=right:Hotel] {H}; \\
            \node [circle, black, draw, label=right:Lunch] {L}; \\
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### EDIT

I probably did't read correctly in the first place, you wanted to resize the +1 only. One way to do this is to add a label to your node, containing the +1 and positionned correctly. I tried this (note the style for every node):

```
\begin{scope}[font=\tiny,every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]
            \node [above=0.5pt of A] {\clock{15}{30} 15:30};
            \node [below=0.5pt of Orig] {\clock{18}{15} 18:15};
            \node [above=0.5pt of H,label={[scale=0.7]10:$+1$}] {\clock{8}{30} 8:30};
```

which leads to this:

[image: different labeling]

You can see the difference betwenn node H (with label) and node E (with the old style). Here's the complete code where *Arrive* is also put as a node label:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/635913/204164

\usepackage{color,xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree, tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.text,backgrounds}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={font issue=\footnotesize},
    font issue/.style={execute at begin picture={#1\selectfont}}
}

\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.17}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{clock}
\usepackage[clock]{ifsym}

\ClockFrametrue\ClockStyle=0

\newcommand{\orig}{\mathcal{O}} % origin position
\newcommand{\dest}{\mathcal{D}} % destination position

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,thick,draw}]
            \node[fill=red!30] (Orig) at (0,0) {$\orig$};
            \node (A) at (2,2) {A};
            \node (B) at (2.3,0.5) {B};
            \node (C) at (3.3,-1.2) {C};
            \node (H) at (4.2,2.1) {H};
            \node (L) at (6.4,-0.5) {L};
            \node (E) at (5.9,1.9) {E} ;
            \node[fill=green!30] (Dest) at (8,1) {$\dest$};
        \end{scope}
        
        \begin{scope}[>={stealth[black]},
            every node/.style={fill=white,circle, inner sep = 0.5pt},
            every edge/.style={draw=red,very thick}]
            \path [->] (Orig) edge node {$5$} (A);
            \path [->] (A) edge node {$5$} (H);
            \path [->] (H) edge node {$3$} (E);
            \path [->] (E) edge node {$8$} (Dest); 
            % \path [->] (B) edge[bend right=60] node {$1$} (E); 
        \end{scope}
    
        \begin{scope}[>={stealth[black]},
            every node/.style={fill=white,circle,inner sep=0.5pt},
            every edge/.style={draw=black,very thick}]
            \path [->] (Orig) edge node {$5$} (B);
            \path [->] (Orig) edge node {$5$} (C);
            \path [->] (B) edge node {$3$} (C);
            \path [->] (B) edge node {$3$} (H);
            \path [->] (B) edge node {$3$} (L);
            \path [->] (C) edge node {$5$} (L);
            \path [->] (E) edge node {$8$} (L); 
            \path [->] (L) edge node {$8$} (Dest); 
        \end{scope}
    

        \begin{scope}[font=\tiny,every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]
            \node [above=0.5pt of A] {\clock{15}{30} 15:30};
            \node [below=0.5pt of Orig] {\clock{18}{15} 18:15};
            \node [above=0.5pt of H,label={[scale=0.7]10:$+1$}] {\clock{8}{30} 8:30};
            \node [above=0.5pt of E,label={[scale=0.7]10:$+1$}]{\clock{10}{45} 10:45};
            \node [above=0.5pt of Dest, align=center,label={[label distance=2pt]above:Arrive},label={[scale=0.7]10:$+1$}] {\clock{12}{00} 12:00};
        \end{scope}

    
        \matrix [draw,above left, row sep=1mm, nodes={font=\scriptsize}] at (current bounding box.north east) {
            \node [circle, black, draw, label=right:Hotel] {H}; \\
            \node [circle, black, draw, label=right:Lunch] {L}; \\
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Not related, but your code could be improved to be shorter, you don't need all those `scope`s.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I used the `\scalebox` command to downsize the `+1`.

The whitespace around the arrow labels is controlled by setting `inner sep`.

Also, I rewrote your code in a way that felt more natural to me, without all the `scope`s. Using `\foreach` is an easy way to set the coordinates and edges, in case you want to add or change any.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{clock}

\ClockFrametrue\ClockStyle=0

\newcommand{\orig}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{O}}} % origin position
\newcommand{\dest}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{D}}} % destination position

\tikzset{vertex/.style={circle, thick, inner sep=0mm, minimum width=7mm, draw}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[vertex, fill=red!30] (Orig) at (0,0) {$\orig$};
\node[vertex, fill=green!30] (Dest) at (8,1) {$\dest$};
\foreach \x/\y/\nm/\lbl in {2/2/A/A,2.3/.5/B/B,3.3/-1.2/C/C,4.2/2.1/H/H,6.4/-.5/L/L,5.9/1.9/E/E} 
    \node[vertex](\nm) at (\x,\y) {\lbl};
\foreach \a\b\lbl in {Orig/B/5,Orig/C/5,B/C/3,B/H/3,B/L/3,C/L/5,E/L/8,L/Dest/8}
    \draw [very thick,-stealth](\a)--(\b) node[circle, fill=white, inner sep=.5mm, midway]{\lbl};
\foreach \a\b\lbl in {Orig/A/5,A/H/5,H/E/3,E/Dest/8}
    \draw [draw=red, fill=black, very thick, arrows={-stealth[black]}](\a)--(\b) node[circle, fill=white, inner sep=.5mm, midway]{\lbl};
\foreach \n\hr\min\day in {A/15/30/,Orig/18/15/,H/8/30/+1,E/10/45/+1,Dest/12/00/+1}
    \node [font=\tiny, above=0.5pt of \n] {\clock{\hr}{\min} \hr:\min${}^{\scalebox{.8}{\day}}$};

\matrix [draw,above left, row sep=1mm, nodes={font=\scriptsize}] at (current bounding box.north east) {
    \node [circle, black, draw, label=right:Hotel] {H}; \\
    \node [circle, black, draw, label=right:Lunch] {L}; \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```